# Навешать обработчик события для элементов.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть такая проблема. Есть массив с данными. Мне надо из этого массива взять данные, создать на основе их объекты, затем задать событие для них. Но вот незадача, на все элементы вешается событие, которое работает с данными последнего элемента массива. И последних созданных элементов (а именно `marker` и `infoWnd`).
*Как* мне сделать так, чтобы для каждого созданного элемента, выполнялась функция со *СВОИМИ* данными?

```
for (var i = 0; i < bonuses.length; i++) {
    var bonus = bonuses[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(bonus.bonus_lat, bonus.bonus_long),
                map: map
            });
    var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: bonus.title
            });

            //Вешаем обработчик события для marker.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function(){
                    //Функция обработчика собития
        infoWnd.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

UPD1: 
Функция обработчика должна работать со своими `marker` и `infoWnd`.

Comment: Откровенно говоря так и не понял на основе чего этот код должен строить разные обработчики событий?

Можно код полностью, а именно - не нужно создания объектов, нужен код обработчиков полностью.

Comment: Обновил. Наш обработчик события вешается функцией   
>>google.maps.event.addListener  

Все происходит внутри цикла. Единственное - это переменная map вне его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
var fn_gen = function ( map, marker, infoWnd ){
  return function(){
    infoWnd.open(map, marker);
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < bonuses.length; i++) {
  var bonus = bonuses[i],
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( bonus.bonus_lat, bonus.bonus_long ),
        map: map
      }),
      infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: bonus.title
      });

          //Вешаем обработчик события для marker.
  google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'mousedown', fn_gen( map, marker, infoWnd ) );
}
```

Comment: Верно. Спасибо.